# How to debug slow mysql

Tags: mysql

I have an SQL query that takes 7 seconds to run on one computer, but on another computer (identical hardware, database has been copied over with mysqldump and so is the same), that same query runs for over 2000 seconds.

How do I find out why this is? All the advice I can find online about debugging slow mysql seems to boil down to 'find the slow queries'. That doesn't help me here. Show processlist doesn't show any other queries running, so why is it taking hundreds of times longer to execute this one on one computer than another?

Comment: Did you try `EXPLAIN` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/using-explain.html?

Comment: You can use `EXPLAIN` to debug the Query.  Mysql execution depends on common factors .

1) Ram memory.
2) System Load.
3) Disk Usage.
4) No Of Cpu Cores.

..etc.

Comment: I know I can use explain to debug a slow query, but the problem is NOT that the query is slow, it is that it is slow on one machine and not on another.

Comment: BTW, explain of the query on the faster machine takes 10 seconds; 35 seconds on the slow one. ALL sql is running slower...

Comment: Are your SYSTEM VARIABLES the same between the two servers?

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is that your SQL Server is same in BOTH conditions. What you are saying is that when query x is executed from client1 it takes few seconds; while from other client client2 it is  taking more than 2000 seconds.

I feel problem is network between client2 and your database server. Try to to ping between these two servers. It should give you some hint. This theory is also supported by the fact that you mentioned that server is NOT showing query getting executed.

If in both conditions SQL Servers are different; while  indexes etc. are identical ; then problem is that ANALYZE has not been executed on client2 since long time.

Comment: Database is local, not an external server. Sorry that wasn't clear from the question. ANALYZE was run recently. Server is showing this query, which is stuck in either state 'executing' or 'sending data' depending on whether any of the LEFT JOIN tables are empty.